# Reshaping of a tensor with adaptive shape results in unexpected resulting shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

i am trying to reshape a tensor with shape (?, 32, 32, 64).
The resulting tensor should be something like (? * 32 * 32, 64).
Tensorflow gives me something like (?, ?) which is unexpected from my point of view, because the last axis' dimension is well defined.

```py
def function(x):
    shape = tf.shape(x)
    x = tf.reshape(x, (shape[0] * shape[1] * shape[2], shape[3]))
```

Reshaping (?, 32, 32, 64) results in (?,?)

Is there a way how to handle this problem?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is because you are are returning the dynamic shape by using tf.shape(x). If you use x.get_shape() this should return the static shape. However, you will need to provide or define the batch size in order to do the reshape operation.